# im trying to put yes /no column to a grid view in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i'm trying to get yes/no to a grid view column the column in question is in database is a bit type value

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enable" SortExpression="Enable">
 <ItemTemplate><%# (Boolean.Parse(Bind("Enable")) ? "Yes" : "No" %></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

this gives me an compile error

Comment: You can add this code code in rowdatabound event & can be bound directly in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Enable").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>
```